# Does weight equate volume or surface area?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help me to determine  how to solve following problems in case of they will come on test

A cubical block of metal weighs $6$ pounds. How much will another cube of the same metal weigh if its sides are twice as long?

My interest is  if it is related to surface  area or  volume? For example let us take cube with side=$2$,then it's surface are is

$6*2*2=24$
and   volume is equal to $2^3=8$;
now let us double it's  side length so we have  side=$4$; then it's surface area is
$6*4*4=96$ and volume is $4*4*4=64$; if we divide new surface area  by old one we get $96/24=4$ and if we divide  new volume by old one we get $64/8=8$; as we see  surface area is increased by $4$ and volume by $8$, so  I have to multiply $6$ by $4$ or $6$    by $8$?or weight of  adjusted cube is $24$ or $48$? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you cut the block in two, say top half and bottom half, and "glue" the two pieces together side by side, which of a) surface area, b) volume, c) weight, change, and which don't?

Comment: or if you prefer take a cube of clay and model it so that it becomes a very large disk :-)

Comment: but it will change both yes?

Comment: Which "both" do you mean?

Comment: surface and volume  weight

Comment: I think that's more of a physics than a mathematics question. Anyway, you can try it out: Take something you can easily weight and divide (say, a piece of butter), weight it, cut it in half (thus increasing the surface, but not the volume), and weight the two halves together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you derivation takes on account both the Surface area and the Volume, I'd like to put this solution in prospective of the second term.

Since I do not know the value of the sides $\ell_{\mathrm{box}}$ an the volume $\ell_{\mathrm{box}}^3$, but I know his weight, then the only factor that correlates them is the Density, which I'll call $\varrho_x$, expressed by:
$$
\varrho_x=\frac{m_{\mathrm{box}}}{\ell_{\mathrm{box}}^3}
$$
Now, if the metal is the same, and so $\varrho_x$ doesn't change, then I could write a simple equation:
$$
\varrho_x=\frac{m_{\mathrm{box}(i)}}{\ell_{\mathrm{box}(i)}^3}=\frac{m_{\mathrm{box}(f)}}{(2\ell_{\mathrm{box}(i)})^3}
$$
The only unknown is $m_{\mathrm{box}(f)}$, so:
$$
m_{\mathrm{box}(f)}=\frac{m_{\mathrm{box}(i)}\cdot 8\ell_{\mathrm{box}}^3}{\ell_{\mathrm{box}(i)}^3}=m_{\mathrm{box}(i)}\cdot 8
$$
As you can see, the difference between the surface area is related to the difference of the volume, so you have to multiply by 8, as this simple $2^3$ times the side of the original lenght.

Let's take a generalized example.

If you imagine one simple cube, with lenght $a$, then the volume and the surface area are:
$$
S=6\cdot a^2,\quad V=a^3
$$
It's true that they have different factors, but they do not mean the same thing: if you imagine the increasing of weight, it's only given by the infinite variation of the Volume, as a simple integral:
$$
V_f=V_i+\left(\int_{a}^{2a}\mathrm{d}a\right)^3
$$
Above it can be observed that one single infintesimal change into the third dimension it's different from a single change of the surface; because the expansion is also inside the cube, which is not counted in the "$4$" factor, as two dimensional.

As you measure only the external surface, the volume takes the "internal expansion" into account, with either the relation of the density and the factor of $2$ "cubed" into the third dimension.

Comment: so it means that volume plays role in changing  weight

Comment: Sure, when there is an expansion, it exists physically into the third dimension, so the projection onto a simple surface doesn't take to account the "real" variation of weight.

Comment: The only important thing is that someone has learned something new, it's always a pleasure to help.

Comment: i agree you absolutely,this is great site,it helps me to prepare for gre

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**- Fill a balloon with some water. Imagine it to have some surface area and volume. Now, press the balloon from one side so that all the water goes to the other side. Keep pressing till the balloon starts to expand, but don't let it explode. What is changing- Surface area or Volume? And why?

Comment: but if water is  in ballon,it means that it touch all side yes of ballon,then if i press from one side,it means that this side would be narrowed and water goes to up,right?it touches to roof of balloon

Comment: Yes, here you are reshaping your object. Is the volume changing? And what about surface area?

Answer (score 1):

**Intuition:** Firstly, you need to understand that volume ($V$) is directly proportional to the weight ($W$), so if we were to be talking about proportions, we can say that $V\propto W$ i.e. $V$ is directly proportional to $W$.

Now the sides of the object ($S$), is related to $V$ as such: $V\propto S^3$.
And, the sides is related to the area ($A$) as such: $A\propto S^2$.

This is why you notice that when you double the sides, you get a $2^2$ increase in area, and a $2^3$ increase in volume/weight.

Comment: so it means that  i should  calculate relationship between new and old volumes and how much times new volume is bigger then old volume,i should multiply weight by this number?

Comment: That is right. The number is the density and the density, $d$, volume $v$ and weight $w$ are related by this equation $w=dv$. (This is assuming uniform density, don't want the applied mathematicians to get up in arms!)